# D3 - Can't create line chart with time data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

This is my first time with D3 and I am trying to create a line chart. I forked from this example: https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart

My fork is here: https://observablehq.com/d/f98c480a077a03ac

My data looks as follows

```
[
  {
    "numAnnotations": 23,
    "date": "2021-04-26"
  },
  {
    "numAnnotations": 108,
    "date": "2021-04-28"
  },
  {
    "numAnnotations": 166,
    "date": "2021-04-29"
  },
...
  {
    "numAnnotations": 227414,
    "date": "2022-04-13"
  }
]
```

I just want to show the number of annotations increasing with date. But I can't get the graph to render and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I am assuming there is something wrong with my data format, but I can't see what's wrong. Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: There is a graph rendering in your fork at the time of writing... ?

Comment: it looks like you figured it out, it's important to convert your date strings into Javascript date objects so d3 can make a time scale

Comment: @RobinMackenzie  -graph is rendering as I figured it out.

Comment: @enjalot - yes you are right, that was it. I was not converting to JS date objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The error was that I was not converting date strings to JS data objects. I have now fixed the code.

Here is the updated observable: https://observablehq.com/d/f98c480a077a03ac